# Using ETag / Last-Modified decorators with Django's class-based generic views

Tags: python, django, http, etag

I've recently migrated all views in one of my Django projects to the new class-based ones. For classic function-based Django views there's a handy decorator `django.views.decorators.http.condition` that can be used to bypass the whole view processing if there's a cached copy matching the conditions that you've specified. I've searched everywhere in the docs and in the source code but can't find any implementation of this for the new class-based views.

So my question is: How would you suggest that I implement conditional view processing for class-based views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there isn't a nice answer to this problem yet.  For decorators that just set function attributes (e.g. `csrf_exempt`), it is enough to apply them to the view class's `dispatch` method, but that obviously doesn't work for the `condition` decorator, since they expect the first function argument to be a request object rather than `self`.

Two ways you could achieve this include:

1. Apply the decorator to the generated view function.  The generic view functionality really boils down to a way of building view functions from classes, so applying the decorator late might be an option.  Something like this:

   ```
   f = ViewClass.as_view()
   f = condition(...)(f)
   ```

   This has the disadvantage that you don't have access to the view class from the functions you pass to the `condition` decorator.  It is also not very convenient if you're calling the `as_view` method in the urlconf.
2. Delegate to a simple function you can apply decorators to inside your view's `dispatch` method.  Something like this:

   ```
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       @condition(...)
       def _dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
           return super(ViewClass, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
       return _dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
   ```

   This one has the benefit that you have access to the view class instance when applying the decorator, so you could use instance methods for your cache validation functions.  A downside is that the decorator will be run every time the view is invoked, but that doesn't look like a problem for this particular decorator.

Both solutions have their problems though, so perhaps it would be worth filing a bug report or asking on the django-users mailing list about how these two concepts should best be combined.

Comment: I actually ended up caching everything on the site as it's very read heavy, only edited a couple of times every week by the administrators. When something changes I clear the whole cache and let a "cache robot" re-visit the most frequently used pages.

Comment: technique 2 works also with the Django Syndication framework, just override `__call__` rather than `dispatch`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following:

```
def conditional(**kwargs):
    '''A wrapper around :func:`django.views.decorators.http.condition` that
    works for methods (i.e. class-based views).

    '''
    from django.views.decorators.http import condition
    from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
    return method_decorator(condition(**kwargs))
```

Comment: If you look at `method_decorator`, you'll see this is basically the same as the second option that James describes.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a complex matter, but recent trends (both for data-/fragment-caching in the server, and for asset caching, in browsers) show that it is better not to spend time in solving the cache invalidation problem, but just do what described in this article:

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works

Real-world example of this technique applied to Django:

http://www.rossp.org/blog/2012/feb/29/fragment-caching/

Answer (score 1):

This short example of how to apply [Conditional View Processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/conditional-view-processing/) to [Django Rest Framework ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) worked for me:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.http import condition

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def last_modified(request):
        return MyModel.objects.latest('my_modified_at').my_modified_at

    @method_decorator(condition(last_modified_func=last_modified))
    def list(self, request):
        return super().list(request)
```