# How to use @condition decorator for REST view classes

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, etag

I am trying to use the ETAG HTTP header to send 304 NOT MODIFIED responses. The following code is used:

```
class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    @condition(etag_func=get_language_etag)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(self.get_cached_response())
```

The problem lies in the 'self' parameter of the get method. This jumbles the parameters in the @condition generator method here the beginning of the condition method:

```
def condition(etag_func=None, last_modified_func=None):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

as now 'self' gets assigned to request and the actual requests ends up in *args.

Has anyone had a similar problem concerning decorators and their expected order of parameters?

Comment: Found the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993951/using-etag-last-modified-decorators-with-djangos-class-based-generic-views

Answer (score 2):

[drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions) provides caching and ETag mixins that you can use on your views, instead of using the ones provided by Django.

https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#cache-etag-mixins

It is not possible to use the methods provided by Django before DRF does not use the standard `HttpResponse` classes, and most of the decorators are expecting it.

Comment: I have successfully used the django etag mixins by using the fix described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993951/using-etag-last-modified-decorators-with-djangos-class-based-generic-views). By creating a superclass that overwrites the dispatch method the code is not that ugly

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-rest-framework-condition](https://github.com/jozo/django-rest-framework-condition)

Install it:

```
pip install django-rest-framework-condition
```

Use it in the same way as decorator from Django:

```
from rest_framework_condition import condition

class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    @condition(etag_func=get_language_etag)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(self.get_cached_response())
```