# How to get the self variable inside the etag_func and last_modified_func functions Django

Tags: django

I am using the django http condition to set the last_modified and e_tag headers.
Here is my set up:

```
def my_last_modified(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return None

def get_etag_key(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return None

class ProductsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.active() # I want to get this value in the functions
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    @condition(etag_func=get_etag_key, last_modified_func=my_last_modified)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProductsListAPIView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

What I want to do is get this variable `queryset` from the main class in the `get_etag_key` and  `my_last_modified` functions.

Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557374/how-to-use-condition-decorator-for-rest-view-classes

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer my question @kamran890. WSGIRequest won't contain the data i am looking for. will it?